# Don't understand this TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, numpy, nonetype

I have the following class:

```
class TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        self.word2weight = None
        self.dim = len(word2vec[next(iter(w2v))])

    def fit(self, X, y):
        tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x)
        tfidf.fit(X)
        # if a word was never seen - it must be at least as infrequent
        # as any of the known words - so the default idf is the max of
        # known idf's
        max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)
        self.word2weight = defaultdict(
            lambda: max_idf,
            [(w, tfidf.idf_[i]) for w, i in tfidf.vocabulary_.items()])

        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.array([
                np.mean([self.word2vec[w] * self.word2weight[w]
                         for w in words if w in self.word2vec] or
                        [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
                for words in X
            ])
```

But when I instantiate it I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-70-dcde03597dd3>", line 23, in <listcomp>
for w in words if w in self.word2vec] or
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Looks like `self.word2vec` is set to `None`. What did you pass as the argument when you created the instance of class `TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you receive an `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error you are trying to do something like `None[0]`.  
 
And your problem is here:

```
self.word2weight = None
```

and then you are trying to access it here:

```
np.mean([self.word2vec[w] * self.word2weight[w]
```

Maybe you need to call the function `fit` first which writes in `word2weight`

Comment: Thank you @Fer Nando! You were right it worked after calling the fit function first